# Wants to create object only one time

Tags: java, swing

I wrote this code for load some strings from database. I want to set those strings to the check boxes in my GUI. This form has 2 buttons named Next and Previous. When I select 2 check boxes and click on next button It will load other string set. Now when I click on previous button, I want to get previously selected check boxes with selected state. These check boxes are creating dynamically.

```
private void loadAnswers(JPanel jp, String qId) {
    jp.removeAll();
    try {
        List<Question> listQuestion = questionController.performSearch(qId);
        ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Question question : listQuestion) {
            if (question.getOpA() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpA().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
            if (question.getOpB() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpB().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
            if (question.getOpC() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpC().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
            if (question.getOpD() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpD().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
            if (question.getOpE() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpE().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
            if (question.getOpF() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpF().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
            if (question.getOpG() != null) {
                answers.add("<html>" + question.getOpG().replace("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
            }
        }
        JCheckBox[] chkBx = new JCheckBox[answers.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < chkBx.length; i++) {
            chkBx[i] = new JCheckBox();
            chkBx[i].setText(answers.get(i));
            jPanel1.add(chkBx[i]);
        }
        jp.repaint();
        jp.revalidate();
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestPane.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestPane.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestPane.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @acdcjunior but without any question the answer is CardLayout

Comment: @mKorbel CardLayout would be fine if the checkboxes are not recreated for each question. If there are plenty of questions and they are dynamic Cardlayout won't suit.

Answer (score 4):

Organize kind a storage for the textboxes (it's better to store model - textbox values). I would suggest a Map. When you have to move to next page go through all the checkboxes and place the values in the Map. On return to the page just go once more extracting the values from the map and set the checkboxes' states.

Key could be answer's text if it's unique or the String from question fields' (question.getOpE())

Comment: One page has more than one answer.

Comment: How can I use a Map for this.